# Eliminate function does not eliminate required boundary/arc?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

Eliminate can eliminate either the common boundary with the adjacent largest polygon or the longest shared boundary.

I want to eliminate/delete common boundry with the third one besides these two.

Can the Eliminate tool do this or is there another tool I need to use?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to include the version and license level of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  In particular the license level may limit/expand your options.  In addition are you able to include a picture of what you are trying to describe because just words is not making that clear to me.

Comment: A picture would be *very* helpful here. From the text an Edit Merge or Dissolve would do it. What "third one"?